# Is it possible in MongoDb to query for patterns that match a given string?

Tags: mongodb

I have a message system where I want different message handlers to be
called depending on the patterns of the incoming messages.

I have this collection:

```
[
    { Pattern: "^a", Handler: "Handler1" },
    { Pattern: "^b", Handler: "Handler2" },
    { Pattern: "^c", Handler: "Handler3" }
]
```

For a given message (a string) I now want to find the first element
where the message matches the pattern and then extract the Handler
name.

That is, for the message "b bla bla bla", I want to extract
"Handler2".

**Note, I don't want to use a regex query to find some string in the
database, it is the other way around:
I want to find the element having a pattern which matches a given
string.**

My solution right now is to fetch the entire list of patterns and
then iterate and match over all the patterns in my application code
and it works fine, but I am wondering if there is some efficient mongo
query which can be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine the way you're doing it right now if the number of patterns is small.

If you have a large number of patterns you'll become a victim of a variation of the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem):
There no easy way to know if a pattern matches (or not) until you actually execute it with your input string (think of the pattern as a mini-program).

**Or:** Given that there is only a finite set of inputs (which is probably not the case), you could store all possible inputs and their corresponding patterns in MongoDB.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to implement the matching check yourself and apply it using map/reduce style.